# SQL - Multiple entries in show one instance in c1 with it's correspondent mapping in c2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

From three tables, using inner join, my results look like this:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ t1.c1 ║ t2.c1 ║ t3.c1 ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║  1a   ║  2a   ║  3a   ║
║  1a   ║  2b   ║  3b   ║
║  1a   ║  2c   ║  3c   ║
║  1b   ║  2a   ║  3a   ║
║  1b   ║  2b   ║  3b   ║
║  1b   ║  2c   ║  3c   ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Is it possible to make it like below?

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ t1.c1 ║ t2.c1 ║ t3.c1 ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║  1a   ║  2a   ║  3a   ║
║       ║  2b   ║  3b   ║
║       ║  2c   ║  3c   ║
║  1b   ║  2a   ║  3a   ║
║       ║  2b   ║  3b   ║
║       ║  2c   ║  3c   ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
SELECT t1.c1, t2.c1, t3.c1
FROM t1
  INNER JOIN t2
    ON t1.c1=t3.c1
  INNER JOIN t3
    ON t3.c1=t2.c1
WHERE t1.c2 = 'n'
ORDER BY t1.c1 ASC
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in SQL? Why not do this in the application layer?

Comment: To make a long story short, the application layer is not designed at all to handle this kind of a request and it would take a great deal of changes to make it possible.

Comment: This is going to be quite sophisticated analytical report in sql, and it will work observably slower than what you already have. You should consider doing this on the application layer indeed.

Comment: @miraclefoxx It will only be run manually and occasionally. Seconds are of no issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use this:

```
SELECT     CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.c1 ORDER BY t2.c1,t3.c1) = 1 THEN t1.c1 END, 
           t2.c1, t3.c1
FROM       t1
CROSS JOIN t2
INNER JOIN t3
ON         t3.c1 = t2.c1
ORDER BY   t1.c1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CASE` and `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1c1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            t1c1 = t1.c1, 
            t2c1 = t2.c1, 
            t3c1 = t3.c1
        FROM t1
        INNER JOIN t2
            ON t1.c1 = t2.c1
        INNER JOIN t3
            ON t3.c1 = t2.c1
        WHERE t1.c2 = 'n'
    )t
)
SELECT
    t1c1 = CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN c.t1c1 ELSE '' END,
    c.t2c1,
    c.t3c1
FROM Cte c
ORDER BY c.t1c1
```

*I replaced your `JOIN` condition on `t2`.*